# LoginController not authenticating users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I was creating a register and login at first, everything was going smoothly and once I finished my register, the login won't authenticate it always says invalid data, trust me there is some valid data it's just not working

I tried changed credentials from 'password' to 'Password' (same for the username), still nothing worked

LoginController, also before you ask I did link them with web.php to the login form and I did add @csrf for the token so everything should be working smoothly

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request){

        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $credentials = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];



        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/register');
        } else {

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

                // Authentication passed...
                $request->session()->flash('loginsuccess', 'loginsuccess');
                return redirect('/');
            } else {
                $request->session()->flash('loginfailed', 'loginfailed');
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the user to be authenticated once they login. (P.S I'm new to Laravel)

Comment: Might be helpful to post the error message.  There is not enough to go on from your question to help you without a little more info.

Comment: Do a `dd($credentials)` and check if it contains what you expect.

Comment: How are you saving the users credentials?

Comment: "Invalid data" suggests it is failing validation. Are you doing any validation elsewhere and can you post an example of the payload you are sending to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this custom auth? If so, I suspect you are storing the hashed password on register but not hashing it on login, that means the passwords don't match.

I'd recomend you to use Laravel's `php artisan make:auth` if you're not doing it already.

Answer (score 0):

There are I couple of things I would check, does the password get crypted after you register a new user?

What happens if you print the credentials?

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){

    $username = $request->input('username');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    dd($password);
    dd($username);// remove the first dd after your check to see the username output
```

Further this logic does not make sense to me:

```
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/register');
    ...
```

Why would you redirect the user if he is already authenticated to your application?
You should redirect him to the main page, something like this:

```
    return redirect('/home'); // or ('/') depends on your routes
```

Further Laravel provides an easy auth scaffolding, you can for instance create a new project `laravel new project` set up a database and run following command `php artisan make:auth` this will built you the login- and register logic.

Comment: Yes I hash the password, and I use the App/User module to save them into the database, I'm going to perform what you have listed above and post back to you - Also, the unneeded redirection methods were all just for debugging purposes, I will redirect a user to a dashboard accessed only to authenticated users

Answer (score 0):

1. Check config/auth.php and make sure you've set a user provider:

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            // Make sure these values are correct
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
```

2. Did you create a custom RegisterController? If so, be sure it is hashing your Users' passwords when their models are being created:

```
$user = User::create([
    'username' => $input['username'],
    'password'=> Hash::make($input['password']),
]);
```

I would start with these two items. If the issue persists, you may want to also include the error message with your question to help track down the issue.